# Emergency Brake Not Released

Tags: emergency-brakes

Drove about 4/10 mile with the Emergency Brake on. I stopped and released the brake. It seems to be braking fine however the brake light is flashing. Any thoughts!

Comment: 4/10 of a mile *shouldn't* have hurt anything. For more help,  please edit your question to include make model year.

Answer (score 1):

If the dash light for brakes is flashing , it is a maintenance issue for pad wear sensors or low fluid